# Odd elements at odd and even elements at even position

Tags: algorithm

This is question asked in one of the interview. Please suggest some view.
Given an array containing all positive integers. You have to arrange elements in such a way that odd elements are at odd position and even elements are at even positions.

PS. No extra space. O(N) solution

Comment: Have you tried solving it at all?

Comment: "Given an array containing all positive integers." That's one big array!

Comment: I just love interview question that have no bearing whatsoever on tasks that might actually be needed for a real-life business requirement.  I'd like to vote the interviewer down a couple of times.  Seriously, they should be asking things like "How do you prevent against SQL Injection?",  "Can you describe XSRF and  XSS to me? ", "How have you handled a situation where a business requirement needed to be changed because you saw that it would cause problems that the business didn't anticipate?"

Comment: I tried solving couldn't get O(n) solution though. My approach was to sort elements and do rearranging after that but turned out to be not good solution.

Comment: @DavidStratton:  You can't solve real-life problems in an interview.  I actually like that question – it's not too hard, and you can see how the canditate approaches the problem.

Comment: Indeed, this one is not hard to do in `O(n)` time and in-place, assuming a solution is possible. If more than half (+1) are even (or more than half (+1) odd) you have problems.

Answer (score 22):

Iterate over the even positions until you find an odd number.  Iterate over the odd positions until you find and even number (using a different index).  Swap the two numbers, and repeat.

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to double the size of the array? Otherwise, the question doesn't make sense. Why?!? assume you are given an array full of odd numbers, can you think of any solution then? No, there is not.

So, I assume that you are allowed to double the size of the array. Then for any i, put the i-element ( a(i) ) into the location 2*i or 2*i +1 depending on whether a(i) is even or odd resp.

Comment: … starting with high indices.

Answer (score 0):

Two two new Arrays OddArray and EvenArray of same size as that of given array. Traverse through the given array and keep sending all the odd to OddArray and keep at odd positions and even number to EvenArray keeping numbers at even positions.

The efficiency will be O(n) and extra memory will be 2n where n is the size of original array.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention no extra space!!

Comment: In the array of size n, can you confirm if there are exactly n/2 odd numbers and n/2 even numbers?

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [5, 7, 6, 8, 10, 3, 4, 9, 2, 1, 12]
odd_list = []
even_list = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    if((list1[i] % 2) == 0):
        even_list.append(list1[i])
    else:
        odd_list.append(list1[i])
print(list1)
j = 0
k = 0
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    if((i % 2 == 0) and (j < len(odd_list))):
        list1[i] = odd_list[j]
        j += 1
    elif(k < len(even_list)):
        list1[i] = even_list[k]
        k += 1
print(list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Putting even number on even position and odd number on odd position
package com.learnJava;

public class ArrangeArray {

    private int [] array={2,5,7,8,1,6,9};
    private int len=array.length;
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ArrangeArray a=new ArrangeArray();
        a.print();
        a.arrange();
        a.print();

    }
    public  void print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public void arrange()
    {
        int oddinx=1;
        int evenidx=0;
        while(true)
        {
            while(evenidx<len && array[evenidx]%2==0)
            {
                evenidx+=2;
            }
            while(oddinx<len && array[oddinx]%2==1)
            {
                oddinx+=2;
            }
            if (evenidx < len && oddinx < len)
                swap (evenidx, oddinx);
            else
                break;

        }

    }
    public void swap(int a,int b)
    {
        int tmp=array[b];
        array[b]=array[a];
        array[a]=tmp;
    }
}
```

Comment: (Indent your code by four more spaces. Don't write, never present uncommented code.) Code-only answers are discouraged. What does this answer add to, say, [Sven Marnach's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13167471/3789665)? What happens if even and odd values don't appear in equal number? (This question doesn't use a "language tag": what language did you code in?)